# How to install wxWidgets on windows 10 using the installer and use it in code::blocks an visual studio 2019 community?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I downloaded wxMSW-3.2.2.1-Setup.exe. How can I use it to install wxWidgets? Does it need any manual configuration or does the installer do all the work for me? After it’s installed, how do I use wxWidgets in Code::Blocks and Visual Studio Community 2019?

I’m using Windows 10. I’ve used Qt for some time, but now I’d like to learn wxWidgets because I found out about the price of the commercial license for Qt. When I used Qt, I just installed Qt Creator using the installer and used it without any manual configuration. I’d like to know if I can download wxWidgets with the same ease.

I want to download wxWidgets from the installer because I don’t want to risk the integrity of my computer by failing to configure it and to save time.

Comment: I do not recommend using the wxWidgets installer. I wrote a getting-started project on GitHub for wxWidgets. Using VCPKG, CMake, and Visual Studio, everything is integrated together. https://github.com/jhanley-com/jhanley-wxwidgets Adding libraries and packages during development becomes very simple. Supports debug and release builds. The wxWidgets team did a very good job integrating their code in VCPKG and Visual Studio. Use those tools.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/v3.2.2.1):

> Finally, Microsoft Windows users may download Setup.exe file containing both sources and documentation, however please note that this file does not contain any binaries, please see below for those.

So if you really want to avoid building wxWidgets yourself, you need to download binaries and not sources. And then see the [instructions for using them](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/3.2/docs/msw/binaries.md), notably verify that you're using a compatible compiler.

Comment: Do these binaries still need to be added to the environment variables? If I download Setup.exe, will it do this for me automatically? Then I would only need to configure the IDE?”

Comment: [link](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Downloading_and_installing_wxWidgets) _italic_ **bold** `This page` says that the installer adds the environment variable. But how do i use wxWidgets in Code::Blocks and Visual studio 2019 community?

Comment: @JMBCODE, check my answer. You can download an official binaries, but building the library is easy and after its done creating the project inside MSVC is straightforward.

Comment: @JMBCODE, do you plan to use MinGW with the C""B?

Comment: What is 'C""B'?

Comment: @JMBCODE, should have been C::B - CodeBlocks.

Comment: @JMBCODE You should follow the linked instructions in the official release notes, not some random wiki pages that could be decades out of date. And I don't know how to explain it more clearly, but the installer doesn't even include binaries so, no, it won't do anything involving them, whatever you mean by "adding binaries to the environment variables".

Comment: @VZ. I was referring to the wxwin environment variable

Comment: The installer does set `WXWIN` but you'd still need to build wx yourself. It's arguably simpler to just unpack the binaries where you need them to be and set the variable manually. Also, using the binaries in the recommended way with MSVS doesn't require this variable at all.

Comment: Ok! I was confused about that. It's the first time i use a 3rd part lib with c++ and have to install it myself. Now I understand. Thank you! 
one more question, Is wxwin required for using the binaries with code::blocks?

Answer (score 1):

@JMBCODE,

You already downloaded and run the Setup binary.

What you need to do now is the following:

1.Open MSVC

2.Go to "File->Open Solution"

3.Navigate to wxWidgets_base_dir\build\msw

4.Open wx_vc15.sln

5.Go to Build->Batch Build

6.Select everything pertaining to Debug configuration and click Build

After some time the build completes

7.Go to File->Open solution

8.Navigate to wxWidgets_base_dir\samples\minimal

9.Open minimal_vcN.sln. Let it convert to the version of the MSVC you have.

10.Build the solution.

11.Run the solution

I don't know why you have 2 IDE installed. You can use either one of those. Granted MSVC doesn't have any RAD tool for wxWidgets development, but you can install 3rd party software like wxGlade (you will need Python and wxPython for it) or any other ones and then program with MSVC.

You should also take a look at different samples in the samples\ directory. Build them, run them see what wxWidgets can do for you. Then look at the code of the samples. Check how controls are created and what is required in order to make your program work.

Do you plan to port your existing software from Qt?

Thank you.

BTW, in order to start your own development wxWidgets provides the `props` file for MSVC.

Create an empty project, copy the file over to that directory and then re-load the project. Everything will be pre-setup for you.

Comment: Thank you! I still don’t know what I’ll do with the software developed with Qt.

Comment: I asked about the 2 IDEs because I haven’t decided which one to use with wxWidgets yet, so I wanted to know how to use each one first. Which one do you recommend? Do you know how to set this up in Code::Blocks?

Comment: @JMBCODE, I don't use C::B simply because MSVC has tyhe free version and it is a native MS tool for development. And it is easy to set up for wxWidgets. However if you want to - there is a pretty good guide on how to use the C::B with wxWidgets - https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47233 and the first one there is https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47231. The only difference is that C::B has a RAD tool integrated and MSVC do not. However that tool is buggy at times and so you can't really rely on it 100%.

Comment: @JMBCODE, I'm pretty satisfied with using MSVC, Xcode and Anjuta and running wxGlade for code generation.